# Some data missing when streaming from arduino to python

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have a question when I tried to receive and read the data from Arduino nano to Python (in raspberry pi), where some data seems to loss like:

```
b',972.63,0,10.00\n'
b'0.00,0,10.00\n'
b'\n'
b'2.62,2150.54,0,10.00\n'
b'\n'
b'61.88,2600.20,0,10.00\n'
b'\n'
b'\n'
b'13.29,1422.29,0,10.00\n'
b'50.24,3396.87,0,10.00\n'
```

And my python code is

```
import serial
serial_port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
baud_rate = 1000000
while True:
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=1)
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)
```

And I checked the serial monitor in Arduino IDE, and didn't find any problems there.
Can I ask is this issue a common situation or how can I avoid this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the baud rate the same between the variable you have set and the rate on the arduino?

Comment: Hi Adid, yes the baud rate are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to initialize serial object every time in a loop,
try move `ser = serial.Serial(...)` out of `while` loop, like

```
ser = serial.Serial(...)
while True:
  data = ser.readline()
  print(data)
```